# Why does my grid layout sometimes break my hover effect?

Tags: html, css, sass

(heads up, very new) So I used a grid layout for most of my page, including an archive. I have it set up so that on larger viewports you see the months full name and abbreviated name on smaller viewports both with :hover effects.

The issue is that the hover effect doesn't work with the abbreviated months (though it does with full months!), and in dev mode I can see it only registering a mouseover on the parent layer. I've tried changing the z-index among other things but it just doesn't work. The ONE THING that I've found that does work is deleting " grid-area:archive; " then the hover effect works again.

How can I use grid and the hover effect in this situation?

```css
.container {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(6, minmax(60px, 1fr));
 gap: 1rem;
 grid-template-areas: 
 "header header header header header header" 
 "archive main  main   main   main   main"
 "....... main  main   main   main   main" 
 "footer footer footer footer footer footer";
}

.small-archive {display: none;}
.full-archive {display: none;}

.archive {grid-area:archive;}

.archive ul {
 background-color: var(--orange);
 li {
  width: max-content;
  a {
   transition: color .3s ease-out;
   color: var(--deepgreen);
   hr {
    color: var(--deepgreen);
   }
   &:hover {
    color: var(--yellow);
   }
  }
 }
}

@media (min-width: 1100px) {
 .full-archive {
  display: block;
 }
}

@media (max-width: 1100px) {
 .small-archive {
  display: block;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <aside class="archive">
      <ul class="small-archive">
          <li><a href="archive.html"> ARCHIVE </a></li><hr/>
          <li><a href="archive.html"> May 2020 </a></li><hr/>
          <li><a href="archive.html"> Apr 2020 </a></li><hr/>
          <li><a href="archive.html"> Mar 2020 </a></li><hr/>
          <li><a href="archive.html"> Feb 2020 </a></li><hr/>
          <li><a href="archive.html"> Jan 2020 </a></li><hr/>
          <li><a href="archive.html"> Dec 2019 </a></li><hr/>
          <li><a href="archive.html"> Nov 2019 </a></li>
      </ul>
  </aside>
  <aside class="archive">
      <ul class="full-archive">
          <li><a href="archive.html">ARCHIVE</a></li><hr/>
          <li><a href="archive.html">May 2020</a></li><hr/>
          <li><a href="archive.html">April 2020</a></li><hr/>
          <li><a href="archive.html">March 2020</a></li><hr/>
          <li><a href="archive.html">Febuary 2020</a></li><hr/>
          <li><a href="archive.html">January 2020</a></li><hr/>
          <li><a href="archive.html">December 2019</a></li><hr/>
          <li><a href="archive.html">November 2019</a></li>
      </ul>
  </aside>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 4 problems here.

1. You should put your classes `.full-archive` and `.small-archive` on the `aside` not the `ul`. Otherwise as you thought one of the aside will always be on the top of the other. (fixed)
2. You forgot to declare your color variables (fixed)

```
:root {
  --orange: orange;
  --deepgreen: darkgreen;
  --yellow: yellow;
}
```

3. You forgot to close your div which would be a problem for the content coming after. (fixed)
4. The size of your columns (max 1/6th of the body) will be too small at some point and your content will overflow. (for you to choose)

Here is the snippet, using CSS (as SCSS is not supported here).

You can also find it in SCSS [here](http://playcode.io/616982/).

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, minmax(60px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header header header header" "archive main  main   main   main   main" "....... main  main   main   main   main" "footer footer footer footer footer footer";
}

.small-archive {
  display: none;
}

.full-archive {
  display: none;
}

.archive {
  grid-area: archive;
}

.small-archive {
  background: darkblue;
}

.full-archive {
  background: darkgreen;
}

:root {
  --orange: orange;
  --deepgreen: darkgreen;
  --yellow: yellow;
}

.archive ul {
  background-color: orange;
}
.archive ul li {
  width: max-content;
}
.archive ul li a {
  transition: color 0.3s ease-out;
  color: darkgreen;
}
.archive ul li a hr {
  color: darkgreen;
}
.archive ul li a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}

@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  .full-archive {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1100px) {
  .small-archive {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <aside class="archive small-archive">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="archive.html"> ARCHIVE </a></li>
      <hr />
      <li><a href="archive.html"> May 2020 </a></li>
      <hr />
      <li><a href="archive.html"> Apr 2020 </a></li>
      <hr />
      <li><a href="archive.html"> Mar 2020 </a></li>
      <hr />
      <li><a href="archive.html"> Feb 2020 </a></li>
      <hr />
      <li><a href="archive.html"> Jan 2020 </a></li>
      <hr />
      <li><a href="archive.html"> Dec 2019 </a></li>
      <hr />
      <li><a href="archive.html"> Nov 2019 </a></li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
  <aside class="archive full-archive">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="archive.html">ARCHIVE</a></li>
      <hr />
      <li><a href="archive.html">May 2020</a></li>
      <hr />
      <li><a href="archive.html">April 2020</a></li>
      <hr />
      <li><a href="archive.html">March 2020</a></li>
      <hr />
      <li><a href="archive.html">Febuary 2020</a></li>
      <hr />
      <li><a href="archive.html">January 2020</a></li>
      <hr />
      <li><a href="archive.html">December 2019</a></li>
      <hr />
      <li><a href="archive.html">November 2019</a></li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, so I just need to restructure it. Thanks @tamarin ! (also I did handle problems 2-4 in my code, but i only posted the part that was specific to my problem. Am I suppsed to post my entire doc?)

Comment: Cool, glad it worked! No you're not supposed to post your entire doc, but be sure to give a snippet (or code) working. If we run your snippet, it's not working because SCSS is not supported. And if we copy the code to another app, we will experience the issues I listed above. There's no way for us to guess that you know how to solve them. It will also save us some time.